# Direct access to URL redirects differently to using in anchor

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've got a very odd situation here and I'm hoping SO's collective knowledge can help.

I'm working on a legacy CakePHP 1.3 application, using the native `Auth` component to secure the majority of the app pages.  However there are *public* pages which are accessible by anyone, and are set up in their controllers using `$this->Auth->allow()`

Now, we have a URL (using Cake's `Router` class) that if typed into a browser, goes straight to the expected page and everything works normally.

**But**, if you use the URL as the `href` of an anchor tag and click the link, you are bounced to the login page of our application as if you had visited a private URL.

*I'm not sure that I can provide the exact URL at the moment though as this is client based public pages, not general public*

We have debugged the routing all the way through and know that it redirects as soon as it hits the final controller action, not higher up in the inheritance chain.

#### Notes on environment:

1. The controller that handles this URL/action inherits from another controller which sets up our public page system
2. Its in a CakePHP plugin, not a direct controller
3. Its CakePHP 1.3
4. This only occurs in non-IE browsers.  IE doesn't display this problem at all

Has anyone come across something similar and has a solution?

As requested in the comment, I've shared some of the code.  Its heavily edited for brevity though so not complete

Public Controller

```
App::import('Controller', 'Events.Bookings');
class PublicBookingsController extends BookingsController
{
    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }
}
```

Booking Controller

```
class BookingsController extends EventsAppController
{
    public new_booking()
    {
        die('Reached new booking');
    }

}
```

Events App Controller

```
App::import('Controller', 'Occurrence');
class EventsAppController extends OccurrenceController
{
    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter(); 
        // various plugin set up code
    }
}
```

Occurrence Controller

```
class OccurrenceController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        // generic plugin setup code snipped
    }
}
```

Route

```
Router::connect('/path/to/url', array('plugin' => 'events', 'controller' => 'public_bookings', 'action' => 'new_booking');
```

Comment: can you share at least some code?

Comment: Edited question to add some code snippets to try and highlight the environment a bit more.